# The static final value is not get from the interface into the servlet

Tags: java, servlets, interface, static, javabeans

I have a weird problem. I have created a public interface like this

```
public interface PricerBeanInterface
{
    public static final double TAX = 37.99;

}
```

and a stateless session bean like this

```
@Stateless
public class PricerBean implements PricerBeanInterface
{    

}
```

Into the servlet I inject through EJB annotation the interface in this way

```
@EJB
private PricerBeanInterface pricerBean;
```

and send the value to the page through the request object

```
request.setAttribute("tax", PricerBeanInterface.TAX);
```

In the jsp page I get the value simply doing ${tax}. Unfortunately I don't get the value. Why?

Comment: What value *do* you get? Are you sure that the setAttribute call is being executed?

Comment: Nothing...an empty value

Comment: Is the line `request.setAttribute("tax", PricerBeanInterface.TAX);` actually being hit?  Can we see the surrounding code?

Comment: it is really really weird...I don't understand why the value is not correctly retrieved